# Express JS Routes Not Working Inside Promise

Tags: node.js, express

Why is the route not being registered here? For some reason, I am getting 404 not found when I access /api/test. When I move the route registration outside the then function, it works. This snippet is added from the app.js from an express generated template.

```
var Q = require('q');

promisify().then(stringText => {
    var route = express.Router();
    route.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hi'));
    app.use('/api', route);
});

function promisify() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  deferred.resolve('Hello World');
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

This works (if you move the route registration outside):

```
var Q = require('q');

var route = express.Router();
route.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hi'));
app.use('/api', route);

promisify().then(stringText => {

});

function promisify() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  deferred.resolve('Hello World');
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

update: Steps to reproduce

1. Create an express template on a folder by typing in `express` from the command line.
2. Then install the packages, `npm install`.
3. Also install the q library, `npm install --save q`
4. Add the code just below the code that register other routes:

   ```
   app.use('/', index);
   app.use('/users', users);

   // Add the code above here
   ```

Comment: My guess is that you're leaving out a "catch-all" handler that gets installed to catch unhandled requests, which in turn will get called _before_ the API handler (because of the order in which the handlers were defined).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error in console? If not have you started the server?. I tried doing your logic (both inside the promise and outside the promise) and I found it working with the code below on http://localhost:3000/api/test

1.Inside Promise Callback

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Q = require('q');

promisify().then(stringText => {
  console.log("called promise success");
  console.log(stringText);
  var route = express.Router();
  route.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send(stringText));
  app.use('/api', route);
});

function promisify() {
  const deferred = Q.defer();

  if (true) deferred.resolve('Hello Chris James');

  return deferred.promise;
}

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

2.Outside Promise callback

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Q = require('q');

var route = express.Router();
route.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hi'));
app.use('/api', route);

promisify().then(stringText => {

});

function promisify() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  deferred.resolve('Hello World');
  return deferred.promise;
}

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "route-check",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start" : "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "q": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is being called. But when you access it via the URL, it is sending 404. If you move out the express.Router outside, the URL can be accessible without issues.

Comment: I accessed the url http://localhost:3000/api3/test via browser and its working fine for me with the above script.

Comment: Oh yeah it works. Thanks. My issue is when inside an express generated template, when you place that code inside app.js.

Comment: can you provide the whole code in the question which I believe would be helpful to debug ?

Comment: I updated the replication steps. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found your code working both outside and inside the promise callback. I updated my answer with full code. Also from your instruction to run the app, you specified only to install the package q, you also have to install the package express to run the application. Included package.json as well for your reference